# jQuery Script not loading at all

Tags: javascript, html, cpanel

I am losing a ton of time trying to diagnose this issue. Any help would be fabulous. This is my first experience using cPanel and I have uploaded my files properly to the `public_html`. The stylesheet and html load beautifully but the js file will not. Any suggestions would be great. Here is my code

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://test.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li.upper").hide();
  $("li.lower").hide();
.....
    console.log(newContent);
    $('#container').html(newContent);
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to place your version of jquery in the public_html directory.

Comment: Is there any error in console ?

Comment: No error in the console. I'll try placing a version of jQuery in my public directory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use CDN. To do that just include this code inside your head tag.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and delete this line of code

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

other wise download jquery library from this [link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js) and paste it on the public_html directory.

Comment: You are awesome. Thank You!!

Answer (score 4):

That is because you are telling the browser to load "jquery-1.12.4.min.js" from your public_html directory but we can see from the screenshot of your folder that it is not there in your public_html directory.

Comment: Ok should I download the jQuery file into my public directory? Sorry I am new to this

Comment: Yes, Biswajit Panday has explained it all. Good luck. :-)

Comment: @RyeGuy, since you have `src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"` then it should be in the same folder level as yoru html page.. if , for example, you have it like `src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"`  then you should upload it into `js` folder which is in same folder level as your page.. Keep in mind you can use CDN for this instead of uploading it.. like http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js or https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js

Comment: Thanks all. And one thing - use the latest stable version of any library (if there is no constrain). jquery 1.12.4 is old enough.